# public static final Lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, static, final, public

Is it considered good practice to group common lambda expressions in a utility class to avoid code duplication ?

What's the best way to do so ? Right now, I have a MathUtils class with a few public static final Functions members :

```
public class MathUtils{
    public static final Function<Long, Long> triangle = n -> n * (n + 1) / 2,
        pentagonal = n -> n * (3 * n - 1) / 2,
        hexagonal = n -> n * (2 * n - 1);
}
```

Comment: It's not lambda expressions you're grouping, it's `Function` values.

Comment: Should i say _common `Function` values_ instead of _common lambda expressions_ ? The question still remains the same; is it considered good practice or should I use regular function ?

Comment: I just want you to make the distinction. Lambda expressions are just syntax. Do whatever is more clear to you and your devs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do it this way

```
public class MathUtils
{
    public static long triangle(long n)
    {
        return n * (n + 1) / 2;
    }
```

And use it like

```
    MathUtils::triangle
```

depending on your taste and use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure your code is correct though.

Comment: Fixed the code, and I would definitely prefer this answer.  Don't bother saving the lambda; write the utility method and then use method references.

Answer (score 1):

Like @SotiriosDelimanolis said, lambda is just syntax. The compiled code will be more or less the same like standard functions. So in this sense, the question becomes:

> Is it considered good practice to group common functions in a utility
>   class to avoid code duplication?

And I'm sure you already know the answer to that question: **Absolutely, that's the whole purpose of the utility pattern**.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.